# How to create smoothly animated text field with custom antialias?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, antialiasing

I'm trying to create a TextField which will look smooth enough when animated. The only option, when I can get smoothly-animated textfield, is setting antiAliasType property to AntiAliasType.NORMAL; But I'd like to play with text antialiasing to make letters a little bit thicker. So I change the antiAliasType to AntiAliasType.ADVANCED.
After that the textfield looks jumpy when animated (it looks like glyphs are being snapped to pixel-grid). Change of property gridFitType of the textField doesn't make any sense.

Has anyone achieved smooth text-field animation when antiAliasType is switched to AntiAliasType.ADVANCED? (The jumpy text occurs when switching to TLF text fields either)

Here is my short code:

```
var p:TextField = new  TextField();
var font:Font = new Font1XXX(); 
// font is embedded int the library and exported as Font1XXX class

var tfor:TextFormat = new TextFormat(); 
tfor.font = font.fontName;
tfor.size = 15;
tfor.color = 0xFFFFFF;
p.defaultTextFormat = tfor;
p.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
p.antiAliasType         = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
p.gridFitType   = GridFitType.NONE; 
// change to GridFitType.NONE does not make any sense;

p.selectable = false;
p.embedFonts = true;
p.text = "HELLO WORLD";
addChild(p);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need selectable text, draw the textfield into a bitmap and add the bitmap to the stage instead of the textfield.

Comment: Yep, this a workaround would work for me. Thanks. But I'd like to now if there are any standard capabilities, and why gridFitType is not affecting anything.

Comment: I wish I could answer that but honestly I have no idea, gridfittype 'should' work imho. Working with text always gave me headaches.

Answer (score 1):

Every text in flash is snapped to whole pixels, resulting in any animation in regards to them will feel "jagged".

Workarounds are to convert any "static text" into a shape and place inside movieclip or to "copy" the text into a bitmap and animate that bitmap. Depending on what type of animation you want to do, different solutions are required for best visual experience.

For instance, scrolling text, it would probably be best to cache it as bitmap and then move it along the axis.

Scaling up/down a text (if it is scaled a lot). This sucks, I haven't found a good way to resolve this without visual artifacts. Best solution is usually to copy the text into another clip, hide the text and then animate quickly or try to cover it with other effects so focus is taken away from the text itself.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Unfortunately I need dynamic text fields. Text is not looking jagged when antialiasType of text field is set to AntiAlias.NORMAL. Caching as bitmap of the textfield does not remove any jagging when antialiasType is set to AntiAlias.ADVANCED. I'm programmatically moving text field by x and y, without scaling.

Comment: "Cache as bitmap" has a lot of quirks, you can't rescale the items in it etc. But you can take a bitmap copy of the text field and then scale that one etc.